# github show differences for entire file

Tags: git, github, sublimetext3

I make some small changes but github show differences for entire files. I suspect it's caused by indentation or default_line_ending.

Strange why would this happens I already have .editconfig in my project. This is the setting. I'm using sublime text 3.

```
root = true
[*]

# Change these settings to your own preference
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
charset = utf-8
max_line_length = 120

# We recommend you to keep these unchanged
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

The error look like this [image]

Comment: Yes, this is most likely caused by lined endings.  Perhaps your Git is changing (or not changing) line endings during checkin/checkout.  Or, it could be your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have installed [EditorConfig](https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime) and make sue you have enabled `show_line_endings` in Sublime Text's properties.
2. Check your the `autocrlf` property in your `.gitconfig` file.
3. f you want to ignore whitespace changes in Github's diff append `?w=1` into the URL.

Comment: I need to install EditorConfig in sublime? I thought a file called .editorconfig in the project is enough? I'm seeing the changes reflect without EditorConfig installed as a package.

Comment: I have `autocrlf = false` in .gitconfig

Comment: Yes SublimeText does not support it natively. Probably your default settings are the similar to the one in your .editorconfig.

What is the eol setting in the .editorconfig?

Comment: `lf`. I posted the snippet of my .editorconfig above.

Comment: Try to add `core.eol = lf` in your `.gitconfig`.